# How to cut off a part from 3D Object?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

How do I cut off a part from an object in SceneKit? For example I take a `SCNSphere` but want to cut right through the middle and only use half of it.

Is this possible in the editor or do I have to do in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SceneKit is not a modelling tool and does not support cutting parts of models. It’s not something you do in code either, especially not with the primitives in SceneKit.

Cutting off parts of an object can be done using so called boolean operations in third part modeling software, but in your case if you want to use half a sphere you dont start with a sphere and cut it in half but create a “hemisphere” in third party software.